# Should REST URL format to return a JSONP response in Jersey always include a "/jsonp"?

Tags: jsonp, jersey

Should the REST URL include a **/jsonp** if I have to implement JSONP using Jersey?

Here is my Jersey code for the method

```
@GET
@Path("/dates/jsonp")
@Produces("application/javascript")
public JSONWithPadding getCompetitionsByDate(
        @QueryParam("dateFrom") String dateFrom,
        @QueryParam("dateTo") String dateTo,
        @QueryParam("callback") String callback) {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
    Date dateF = null;
    Date dateT = null;
    try {
        dateF = df.parse(dateFrom);
        dateT = df.parse(dateTo);
    } catch (ParseException parseExp) {
        return null;
    }
       List<Competition> competitions = context.getCompetitions(
            dateF, dateT);
    GenericEntity<List<Competition>> compGenericEntity = new GenericEntity<List<Competition>>(competitions) {};
    JSONWithPadding padding = new JSONWithPadding(compGenericEntity,
            callback);
    return padding;
}
```

When I deploy and load the URL on the browser, this returns the correct JSON padded with the callback method, but when I change the path to `@Path("/dates?enable=jsonp")`, it doesn't work and returns an XML representation of the the competitions.

I am using JSON 1.10 and the app is deployed on Glassfish 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

q: Should the REST URL include a /jsonp if I have to implement JSONP using Jersey?
a: not necessarily (it can be included, but doesn't need to be).

your other issue is that you are putting query params into @Path value, which is not possible; see http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/Path.html.

you can have something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/dates")
@Produces("application/javascript")
public JSONWithPadding getCompetitionsByDate(
    @QueryParam("dateFrom") String dateFrom,
    @QueryParam("dateTo") String dateTo,
    @QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    ...
}

@GET
@Path("/dates")
@Produces("application/xml")
public ... getCompetitionsByDate(
    @QueryParam("dateFrom") String dateFrom,
    @QueryParam("dateTo") String dateTo,
    @QueryParam("callback") String callback) {

    ...
}
```

and differentiate between these to by setting proper "accept" header in your request.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment "other issue is that you are putting query params into Path value". If you look closely I am not specifying query parameters separately. Only difference is my @Path have ("/dates/jsonp") as the value. Could you point where I am wrong?

Comment: c&p your paragraph: ""When I deploy and load the URL on the browser, this returns the correct JSON padded with the callback method, but when I change the path to @Path("/dates?enable=jsonp"), it doesn't work and returns an XML representation of the the competitions.""

Comment: Oh OK, I thought since that is not going to change I can put it in Path. Thanks I will let you know